# How to interpret economic significance with the left side is natural log variable and right side is decile ranking variable

Tags: regression

Hi I have searched for many articles but still confused about the interpretation of the economic significance. Here is the result:

ln(fees)=10.15+0.18 size (decile rank variable)+ other variables.

How should I interpret the coeficient 0.18? Can I just say one unit increase in size will be associated with 1.8% increase fees? or should I do 0.18*std of size then take exp? Thanks!!